# Blog Pagination in Sitefinity

Tags: pagination, telerik, blogs, sitefinity

I modified an existing template of blog widget to show only what I really needed. Now, I want to add a custom pagination that has next and previous buttons, and can display up to 5 list of pages based on the current page.

Plese see below:

<< 1 2 3 4 5 >>

or

<< 7 8 9 10 11 >>

Below is my template.

```
 <%@ Control Language="C#" %>
 <%@ Register TagPrefix="sf" Namespace="Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.ContentUI" Assembly="Telerik.Sitefinity" %>
 <%@ Register TagPrefix="sf" Namespace="Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.Comments" Assembly="Telerik.Sitefinity" %>
 <%@ Register TagPrefix="sf" Namespace="Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI" Assembly="Telerik.Sitefinity" %>
 <%@ Register TagPrefix="sf"    Namespace="Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.PublicControls.BrowseAndEdit" Assembly="Telerik.Sitefinity" %>
 <%@ Register TagPrefix="telerik" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" %>
 <%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Sitefinity" Namespace="Telerik.Sitefinity.Modules.Comments.Web.UI.Frontend" TagPrefix="comments" %>
 <%@ Import Namespace="Telerik.Sitefinity" %>   
 <%@ Import Namespace="Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI" %>



 <telerik:RadListView ID="Repeater" ItemPlaceholderID="ItemsContainer" runat="server" EnableEmbeddedSkins="true" EnableEmbeddedBaseStylesheet="true">
<LayoutTemplate>

        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="ItemsContainer" runat="server" />
</LayoutTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <div data-sf-provider='<%# Eval("Provider.Name")%>'  data-sf-id='<%# Eval("Id")%>' data-sf-type="Telerik.Sitefinity.Blogs.Model.BlogPost">

        <h2>
            <sf:DetailsViewHyperLink TextDataField="Title" ToolTipDataField="Description" data-sf-field="Title" data-sf-ftype="ShortText" runat="server" />
        </h2>
        <p><small>
            <asp:Literal ID="Literal2" Text="<%$ Resources:Labels, By %>" runat="server" />
            <sf:PersonProfileView runat="server" />
            <sf:FieldListView ID="PostDate" runat="server" Format=" | {PublicationDate.ToLocal():MMM dd, yyyy}" />
            <!--<comments:CommentsCountControl runat="server" ID="commentsCounterControl" AllowComments='<%# Eval("AllowComments") %>' ThreadKey='<%# ControlUtilities.GetLocalizedKey(Eval("Id")) %>' ThreadType='<%# Container.DataItem.GetType().FullName %>' DisplayMode="ShortText"/>-->
          </small>
        </p>

    <br />
        <sf:FieldListView ID="PostContent" runat="server" Text="{0}" Properties="Content" WrapperTagName="div" WrapperTagCssClass="sfpostContent" EditableFieldType="LongText"/>
      <br/>         
        <%--
        <div class="sfpostCategoriesAndTagsWrp">
            <sitefinity:HierarchicalTaxonField ID="HierarchicalFieldControl" DisplayMode="Read" BindOnServer="true" runat="server" TaxonomyId="E5CD6D69-1543-427b-AD62-688A99F5E7D4" WebServiceUrl="~/Sitefinity/Services/Taxonomies/HierarchicalTaxon.svc" Expanded="false" TaxonomyMetafieldName="Category" Title="Categories" ResourceClassId="TaxonomyResources" HideWhenNoTaxaFound="true" />
            <sitefinity:FlatTaxonField ID="FlatFieldControl" DisplayMode="Read" BindOnServer="true" runat="server" TaxonomyId="CB0F3A19-A211-48a7-88EC-77495C0F5374" WebServiceUrl="~/Sitefinity/Services/Taxonomies/FlatTaxon.svc" Expanded="false" TaxonomyMetafieldName="Tags" Title="Tags" ResourceClassId="TaxonomyResources" HideWhenNoTaxaFound="true" CssClass="sfpostTagsWrp" />
        </div>
        --%>
    </div>
 </ItemTemplate>
 </telerik:RadListView>

 <ul class="pagination">
 <sf:Pager ID="pager" runat="server">
 </sf:Pager>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple links describing how to override the default functionality of the built in Sitefinity pager:

http://blog.falafel.com/blogs/george-saadeh/2012/01/05/extending_sitefinity_pager_control

http://www.sitefinity.com/blogs/team-blog/2011/12/14/extending_the_default_pager_control

At the bottom of both are links to download the source code.